# how to postpone a function call in c

Tags: c

I am trying to postpone a function call (using a function wrapper), by saving its arguments in a list of void pointers:

```
void *args[]
int argt[]
```

The argt is used in order to remember the data type stored at void * location.

Later, I need to call the postponed function:

```
function(args[0], args[1])
```

but the problem is that I must specify their type correctly.

I use a macro, like this:

```
#define ARGTYPE(arg, type) type == CHARP ? (char *) arg : (type == LONGLONG ? *((long long *) arg) : NULL)
```

and the function call becomes:

```
function(ARGTYPE(args[0], argt[0]), ARGTYPE(args[1], argt[1]))
```

I have two issues:

1) warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression, generated by the macro definition (please note I can live with it, see 2))

2) the real problem: the long long argument isn't passed correctly (i get 0 every time)

**I am clearly missing something, so can anyone please explain (in details) why the macro isn't working properly, or suggest another approach?**

`EDIT`: I add here the storing arguments part (the relevant details, I parse a va_list), it gets their type based on a format specifier:

```
while (*format)
{
    switch(*format)
    {
        case 's':
            saved_arguments[i] = strdup(arg);
            break;
        case 'l':
            saved_arguments[i] = malloc(sizeof(long long));
            *((long long *) saved_arguments[i]) = arg;
            break;
    }
    i++;
    format++;
}
```

Comment: How is `function` declared? If it depends on the arguments, how do you decide which function to call?

Comment: It looks like libffi is *close* to what you want, at least for the dynamic dispatch. It doesn't exactly help with the delaying part, but that is likely to be specific to the platform you are targeting. Give us some information about your platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX, etc.), and we can help you more.

Comment: @jxh, `function` is like printf, it can take arguments of different types. All I need is to pass to the function the correctly casted (stored earlier) arguments.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: `printf()` gets hints about the type from the format specifiers. Why don't you pass `argt` into `function()`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I am using a custom version of Linux, with limited libraries installed. I am relying on pure c. Also, I don't need a delay based on a timeout, it don't have to be asynchonous.

Comment: @jxh, I sort of do that already, the function have the correct format specifiers, it will call vprintf. The problem seems that if not correctly casted arguments will somewhere lose some bytes...

Comment: Okay, this is detail missing from your question. `function` is really a `vprintf()` ?

Comment: @jxh, no, it is sort of a vprintf wrapper. Sorry about the misconception.

Comment: In the code that stores the function parameters, you use the `arg` variable regardless of associated index of the `saved_arguments` array, is that a typo?

Comment: @GearoidMurphy, no arg get's updated every iteration, as parsing the va_list. I just did not show (think it is irrelevant) that in the code.

Answer (score 9):

Your warning is caused by the ternary operators having multiple types in their sub-expressions, i.e.:-

```
cond ? expression of type 1 : expression of type 2
```

the two expressions need to evaluate to the same type, which doesn't really help you much.

To solve your problem, I can think of two solutions, both of which are a bit nasty.

1. Use VARARGS / variadic functions

   Define your function using the '...' parameter and store the parameters somewhere using the given macros and define the target function as accepting a va_list. You do lose every bit of type safety, compiler checking and require extra meta data for the functions as well as re-writing the target function to use a va_list.
2. Drop to assembler and hack the stack

Told you it was nasty. Given a function to call:-

```
void FuncToCall (type1 arg1, type2 arg2);
```

create a function:-

```
void *FuncToCallDelayed (void (*fn) (type1 arg1, type2 arg2), type1 arg1, type2 arg2);
```

which copies the parameters on the stack to a dynamically allocated block of memory which is returned. Then, when you want to call the function:-

```
void CallDelayedFunction (void *params);
```

with the pointer the call to FuncToCallDelayed returned. This then pushes the parameters onto the stack, and calls the function. The parameters and the function pointer are in the params parameter.

This method does tie you to a specific processor type but at least keeps some form of type checking on the parameter list.

**Update**

Here's a version of Method 2, built for Visual Studio 2012, IA32, running on Win7:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

__declspec (naked) void *CreateDelayedFunction ()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov esi,ebp
        mov eax,[esi]
        sub eax,esi
        add eax,4
        push eax
        call malloc
        pop ecx
        or eax,eax
        jz error
        mov edi,eax
        sub ecx,4
        mov [edi],ecx
        add edi,4
        add esi,8
        rep movsb
      error:
        ret
    }
}

void CallDelayedFunction (void *params)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov esi,params
        lodsd
        sub esp,eax
        mov edi,esp
        shr eax,2
        mov ecx,eax
        lodsd
        rep movsd
        call eax
        mov esi,params
        lodsd
        add esp,eax
    }
}

void __cdecl TestFunction1 (int a, long long b, char *c)
{
    cout << "Test Function1: a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = '" << c << "'" << endl;
}

void __cdecl TestFunction2 (char *a, float b)
{
    cout << "Test Function2: a = '" << a << "', b = " << b << endl;
}

#pragma optimize ("", off)

void *__cdecl TestFunction1Delayed (void (*fn) (int, long long, char *), int a, long long b, char *c)
{
    return CreateDelayedFunction ();
}

void *__cdecl TestFunction2Delayed (void (*fn) (char *, float), char *a, float b)
{
    return CreateDelayedFunction ();
}

#pragma optimize ("", on)

int main ()
{
    cout << "Calling delayed function1" << endl;
    void *params1 = TestFunction1Delayed (TestFunction1, 1, 2, "Hello");
    cout << "Calling delayed function2" << endl;
    void *params2 = TestFunction2Delayed (TestFunction2, "World", 3.14192654f);
    cout << "Delaying a bit..." << endl;
    cout << "Doing Function2..." << endl;
    CallDelayedFunction (params2);
    cout << "Doing Function1..." << endl;
    CallDelayedFunction (params1);
    cout << "Done" << endl;
}
```

** Another Update **

There is a third option, as I mentioned in the comments, and that is to use a messaging system. Instead of calling a function, create a message object of the form:-

```
struct MessageObject
{
   int message_id;
   int message_size;
};

struct Function1Message
{
   MessageObject base;
   // additional data
};
```

and then have a lookup between message_id and actual functions, with the functions and the lookup defined like:-

```
void Function1 (Function1Object *message)
{
}

struct Lookup
{
  int message_id;
  void (*fn) (void *data);
};

Lookup lookups [] = { {Message1ID, (void (*) (void *data)) Function1}, etc };
```

Comment: I am actually storing the variables from a va_list. It would be so nice if I could copy a va_list for later use :(. I considered the second variant, but still, I thought it should work with the macro.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky But, you *can* copy a va_list... [va_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_copy).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, the copy only works in the current function scope, as it is usually bound to the stack. My function wrapper (which does the savings), will exit, and the copied va_list will be broken. At some point later, I'll call `function`, but no va_list will be available.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Gotcha. In that scenario, you either have to reinvent the wheel, or use a library like libffi. It's really your best option.

Comment: This solution, whilst impressive, is still limited to x86 architectures and somewhat brittle.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: Brittle? Hmmmm. Yes, the version I've posted is limited to IA32, but the idea is sound - grab the stack frame just prior to calling the function and save it somewhere and when the function is actually called, recreate the stack frame from the stored data. I suppose the ideal solution would be to use a messaging system of some description, where messages are held in limbo until ready to be processed.

Comment: @Skizz, It also assumes the cdecl convention, which is not used on the IA64 ABI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: But an IA64 version is still possible using this idea. I never said the version I gave was portable to IA64 or other processors.

Comment: @Skizz, Ok true, but my concern with a technically advanced, low-level solution like this is that it's always predicated upon a set of assumptions on the target architecture, I would personally prefer a solution that leveraged the compiler to coordinate the argument stacking but I don't see how it's possible in this case

Comment: For a much more portable solution to many different CPU architectures, consider using the [ffcall library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/); see my answer for an example of how that might be used.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is failing because the true and false result operands of the `?:` operator need to be compatible types.

My original suggestion that you create a function call wrapper macro that expands the arguments with every possible combination is not really a viable solution to you given that you actually want to support more than just two types and two arguments.

It occurred to me that you could use [`swapcontext()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/makecontext) and [`setcontext()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) to postpone the call. Basically, instead of stashing away the arguments into a data structure, and returning from your print function for a future call that unpacks your stashed arguments, you use `swapcontext()` to jump to the function you want to take over until such time that your print can resume. If you only need to flip back and forth, you only need two contexts.

```
struct execution_state {
    /*...*/
    ucontext_t main_ctx_;
    ucontext_t alt_ctx_;
    char alt_stack_[32*1024];
} es;
```

Your print function could look something like this:

```
void deferred_print (const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    while (need_to_defer()) {
        /*...*/
        swapcontext(&es.main_ctx_, &es.alt_ctx_);
    }
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Where `alt_ctx_` is initialized to a rendezvous function that takes over execution until the print can resume. When the print can resume, the print context is restored with:

```
    setcontext(&es.main_ctx_);
```

I coded up a toy example, you can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/S6qCdq).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would gladly pass the argt to the function, but the function does some processing and ultimately calls vprintf. Also, I have 5+ arguments, so the FUNCTION macro isn't a solution...

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: I'm curious to know what you think of my new suggestion.

Comment: i'll let you know as soon as I finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [foreign function call library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/), it takes care of all the grungy platform-specific details for you.  For example, here's how you might postpone a function call to a function taking an `int`, `void*`, and `long long` parameters and returning `int`:

```
#include <avcall.h>

int my_function(int a, void *b, long long c)
{
    // Do stuff
}

...

av_list alist;    // Stores the argument list
int return_value; // Receives the return value

// Initialize the argument list
av_start_int(alist, &my_function, &return_value);

// Push the arguments onto the list
av_int(alist, 42);                 // First arg 'a'
av_ptr(alist, &something);         // Second arg 'b'
av_longlong(alist, 5000000000LL);  // Third arg 'c'

// We're done -- stash away alist and return_value until we want to call the
// function later.  If the calling function needs to return, then you'll need
// to allocate those variables on the heap instead of on the stack

...

// Now we're ready to call the stashed function:
av_call(alist);
// Return value from the function is now stored in our return_value variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum e_type {
    CHAR = 0,
    INT,
    LONG,
    CHARPTR
};

struct type {
    enum e_type type;
    union {
        char c;
        int i;
        long l;
        char *s;
    } value;
};

#define convert(t) (t.type == CHAR ? t.value.c : (t.type == INT ? t.value.i : (t.type == LONG ? t.value.l : t.value.s)))

void test_fun(int argc, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i = 0, curr = 0;
    struct type t;

    va_start(args, argc);

    while (i++ < argc)
    {
        t = va_arg(args, struct type);

        switch (t.type) {
            case CHAR:
                printf("%c, ", convert(t));
                break;

            case INT:
                printf("%d, ", convert(t));
                break;

            case LONG:
                printf("%ld, ", convert(t));
                break;

            case CHARPTR:
                printf("%s, ", convert(t));
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    va_end(args);
}

void test_fun2(char c, long l, char *s)
{
    printf("%c, %ld, %s\n", c, l, s);
}

int main()
{
    struct type t1, t2, t3;
    t1.type = CHAR;
    t1.value.c = 0x61;

    t2.type = LONG;
    t2.value.l = 0xFFFF;

    t3.type = CHARPTR;
    t3.value.s = "hello";

    test_fun(3, t1, t2, t3);
    test_fun2(convert(t1), convert(t2), convert(t3));

    return 0;
}
```

The secret here is to use the union.

This code will give a lot of warnings because the compiler cannot correctly figure the type of the returned value from the macro.

The code above will correctly print:

```
a, 65535, hello, 
a, 65535, hello
```

(Tested with gcc and clang on linux)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following way to solve this. First of all let's get rid of argument type checking during the function call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int a, long long b)
{
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    printf("b = %lld\n", b);
    return 0;
}

int function2(double c, char *d)
{
    printf("c = %f\n", c);
    printf("d = %s\n", d);
    return 0;
}

typedef int (*ftype)(); // The type of function which can take undefined number of arguments and return 'int'

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ftype f1, f2;

    f1 = (ftype)function;
    f2 = (ftype)function2;
    f1(10, 100500);
    f2(2.3, "some string");
    return 0;
}
```

Then we can implement the "dispatcher" which will perform the function call correctly:

```
int dispatch(void **args, int call_type, ftype function)
{
    int ret_val;
    switch(call_type)
    {
        0: ret_val = function(*(int*)args[0], *(double*)args[1]);
           break;
        1: ret_val = function(*(long long*)args[0], *(int*)args[1]);
           break;

        etc etc...
    }
}
```

The main drawback of this approach is necessity to implement a lot of cases for dispatcher. And of course it will work only if all of those cases are defined a priori.

Finally, I should say that it is extremely unsafe implementation. It easily can become a source of strange and dangerous errors.

Comment: If you want `ftype` to take any number of arguments, standard way is to let it take `...` instead of not specifying any arguments.

Comment: You will need to use `va_list` inside of every called function to obtain arguments. Here I assume that we cannot change those functions code. Empty braces will work in this case, `...` will not.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use `g_timeout_add_seconds()`

Sets a function to be called at regular intervals with the default priority, G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT. The function is called repeatedly until it returns FALSE, at which point the timeout is automatically destroyed and the function will not be called again.

Comment: -1, non-standard, only works when using GTK (which the OP didn't state he was using).